# Intercept root requests from app in Java app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, root

I've searched a lot here on the site and online but I haven't been able to find a proper answer. So I'm actually going to make an application that shows a dialog window when an app (doesn't matter what) is requesting root. The only one problem is that I don't know a good java code that will use a listener which will intercept every time that an app is requesting root and show my dialog window.

To be more clear I want to do something like Root managing app (such as SuperSU) that will show a dialog window with allow or deny permissions every time that an request su permission.

I have all my app ready, with codes layouts and so on, I'm just missing this coding part. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Short of your writing a custom ROM, I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: Well SuperSU is just an app that intercept root requests from its own su binary. so maybe it's easier if i show a dialog window when the activity of superSU is called? for example...

Comment: You cannot "show a dialog window when the activity of superSU is called" on modern versions of Android, because you do not know when that activity is invoked.

Comment: Well app locker apps show a full screen activity when the main activity of select apps are called. Isn't it possible to use this kind of coding?

Comment: Google has been taking steps in the past couple of years to prevent apps from finding out what is in the foreground, for privacy and security reasons. If app lockers still work, they are exploiting some sort of flaw which will hopefully get fixed.